# Send data from Node.js back to Client

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an IOS React Native App which uses Node.js program to download photos from Google Cloud bucket. I could get the photos from specific folder but I am not able to send them back to client. Below is the Client Node.js program:

index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
const uploadImage = require('./helpers/helpers')
const downloadImage = require('./helpers/downloadhelpers');

const app = express()

const multerMid = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    // no larger than 5mb.
    fileSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024,
    //fileSize: maxSize
  },
})

app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.use(multerMid.single('file'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))

app.post('/uploads', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const myFile = req.file
    const destination = req.body.folder_name;

    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile, destination)
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        message: "Upload was successful",
        data: imageUrl
      })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.get('/file_download', async (req, res, next) => {
  const folder_name = req.body.folder_name;
  try {
    const ImageDownload = await downloadImage(folder_name)
    console.log(ImageDownload);
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        message: "Download Successful",
        data: ImageDownload
      })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    error: err,
    message: 'Internal server error!',
  })
  next()
})

app.listen(9001, () => {
  console.log('app now listening for requests!!!')
})
```

Below is the upload node which is working nice as purposed:

helpers.js

```js
const util = require('util');
const gc = require('./../config')
const bucket = gc.bucket('jtg_app_bucket') // should be your bucket name

module.exports = uploadImage = (File, destination) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const {
    originalname,
    buffer
  } = File
  const folder_name = destination;
  console.log(folder_name);
  const blob = bucket.file(destination + '/' + originalname.replace(/ /g, "_"))
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false
  })
  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
      const publicUrl = util.format(
        `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${folder_name.name}/${blob.name}`
      )
      resolve(publicUrl)
    })
    .on('error', () => {
      reject(`Unable to upload image, something went wrong`)
    })
    .end(buffer)
})
```

Below is the download node which sends data after fetch from GCP bucket:

downloadhelpers.js

```js
module.exports = downloadImage = (FolderToDisplay) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const folder_name = FolderToDisplay;
  const {
    Storage
  } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  var projectId = '*****************' // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  var keyFilename = './../UploadPhotosNode/config/keys.json'
  const storage = new Storage({
    keyFilename,
    projectId
  });
  var bucket = storage.bucket("gs://jtg_app_bucket");
  const bucketName = 'jtg_app_bucket';

  // The directory prefix to search for
  const prefix = folder_name + '/';

  // The delimiter to use
  const delimiter = '/';
  const options = {
    prefix: prefix,
  };

  bucket.getFiles(options).then(results => {
      const files = results[0];
      var resData = {
        success: true,
        images: {
          results: []
        }
      };
      files.forEach(file => {
        resData.images.results.push({
          uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' + bucketName + '/' +
            file.name
        });
      })
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(resData);
      var only_images = JSON.parse(stringified);

      const data = only_images.images.results;
      console.log(data);
      resolve(data)

    })
    .on('error', () => {
      reject(`Unable to download images, something went wrong`)
    })
    .end(buffer)
})
```

Below is the data I am getting from the download node program:

```json
[
  { "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/image.jpg" },
  { "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/loved_it.jpg" }
]
```

I need to send data using resolve(data) like in upload node program and I am not able to do that. Can anyone suggest how to do that? Thanks in advance.

I am getting the data in const data in console, I want to send that back inside resolve() to /file_download in index.js. In Postman, when I run "http://localhost:9001/file_download", I am getting error as:

```json
{
  "error": {},
  "message": "Internal server error!"
}
```

I want the output as

```json
{
  "message": "Download Successful",
  "data": [
    { "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/image.jpg" },
    { "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/loved_it.jpg" }
  ]
}
```

So that I can use this to display the images inside React Native App. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Don't use images to convey code or error messages please.  [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Yes..I edited the question.

Comment: Can you please describe that actual results compared to your expected results?  It looks like you have some code in place that attempts to do what you intended.  So what happened?  What went wrong?  Why are you "not able to do that"?

Comment: I have added few points in the question above, what I intend to do.Thanks

Comment: I suggest that where you have `catch (error)` you add code to immediately do `console.error(error)` so that you can see what the exception was.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed last three lines from downloadhelpers.js and it is working fine.

Below is the correct download node.

downloadhelpers.js

```
module.exports = downloadImage = (FolderToDisplay) => new 
 Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const folder_name = FolderToDisplay;
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var projectId = 'vast-service-281617' // Your Google Cloud Platform 
project ID
var keyFilename = './../UploadPhotosNode/config/keys.json' 
const storage = new Storage({keyFilename,projectId});
var bucket = storage.bucket("gs://jtg_app_bucket");
const bucketName = 'jtg_app_bucket';
// The directory prefix to search for
const prefix = folder_name+'/';
// The delimiter to use
const delimiter = '/';
const options = {
prefix: prefix,
};  

bucket.getFiles(options).then(results => {  
const files = results[0];
var resData = {
          success: true,
          images: {
             /*  id:[], */
              results: []
          }  
      }; 
  files.forEach(file => {
      
  resData.images.results.push({
   uri:'https://storage.googleapis.com/'+bucketName+'/' +file.name});
      
    }) 
   var stringified = JSON.stringify(resData);
   var only_images = JSON.parse(stringified);

   const data  = only_images.images.results; 

   console.log(data);
   resolve(data)
   })
   })
```

Below is the result from Postman:

```
{
"message": "Download Successful",
"data": [
    {
        "uri": 
     "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "uri": 
   "https://storage.googleapis.com/jtg_app_bucket/device_6/loved_it.png"
    }
  ]
 }
```